# Prove that $f[x_0,x_0,x_1]=f'[x_0,x_1]$ for divided difference

Tags: numerical-methods

Prove that $f[x_0,x_0,x_1]=f'[x_0,x_1]$ for divided difference

Attempt

RHS
\begin{align*}
 f'[x_0,x_1]&=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f[x_0+\epsilon,z_1]-f[x_0,x_1]}{\epsilon}
 \end{align*}

LHS \begin{align*}
f[x_0,x_0,x_1]&=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}f[x_0,x_0+\epsilon,x_1]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f[x_0,x_0+\epsilon]-f[x_0+\epsilon,x_1]}{x_0-x_1}\\
&=\frac{\frac{f(x_0+\epsilon)-f(x_0)}{\epsilon}-\frac{f(x_0+\epsilon)-f(x_1)}{x_0+\epsilon-x_1}}{x_0-x_1}
\end{align*}

How to show that they are equal?

Comment: This notation is very specific to where the question came from, and it is unlikely anyone will be able to answer it currently. Please provide a full definition, so that we can help you to answer your question. It would also help to know any steps you have taken to try to answer it yourself.

Comment: @preferred_anon Hope it is correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{f[x_0+\epsilon,x_1]-f[x_0,x_1]}{\epsilon}=f[x_0+\epsilon,x_1,x_0]
$$
and that the order of the argument points does not matter in divided differences.